# How to fix an URP Error in Unity3D after cloning it from github?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

When I'm trying to create a new URP asset, I'm getting an error:

> `Exception: Cannot load. Path Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Runtime/Data/XRSystemData.asset is correct but AssetDatabase cannot load now. UnityEngine.Rendering.ResourceReloader.Load (System.String path, System.Type type, UnityEngine.Rendering.ReloadAttribute+Package location) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@14.0.9/Runtime/Utilities/ResourceReloader.cs:224)`

And

> No script asset for UniversalRenderPipelineGlobalSettings. Check that the definition is in a file of the same name and that it compiles properly.

I tried to reinstall an URP and it didn't help. Re imported to another project files and also didn't help.

Comment: do you open project with same unity version?  
I suggest add your unity and URP version for more information

Comment: yep, unity editor version is 2022.3.11f and the urp version is 14.0.9.